# Convert a scanned PDF table to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pdf, ocr

I have a scanned PDF which has some random data in a tabular format and want to copy that into an Excel sheet.

I have played around with digital PDFs and use 'tabula' to extract tables but scanned PDFs require OCRs(what I've seen over google).
I know there is an OCR involved(tesseract), but do not know what approach should I take towards solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Tesseract's TSV (Tab Separated Value) output format and see if Excel can read or import it. Some tranformation may be needed to get it into a format consumable by Excel.

https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/manuals/tesseract.1.html